# How to use xulrunner in C# Application?

Tags: c#, xulrunner, gecko

I have seen GeckoFX and mozilla activex control but they are outdated.

Latest stable xulrunner is 8 and beta is 9. It would be nice to use those instead of old 1.9 (for GeckoFX)

Are there any info and/or documentation on latest xulrunner in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get geckofx for xulrunner 8.0 from here:
https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-8.0/